# C# Find properties shared by two types of the same hierarchy

Tags: c#, optimization, reflection

I need to copy the value of properties from one class to another that are descendants of the same base type. Source and target object may be on different levels of the same inheritance branch, meaning one is derived from the other, or be descendant of different branches, meaning they share a common base type.

```
      A
  B1      B2
C1 C2      C3
```

From the structure above I may want to copy all properties from A to C1, C2 to C3, C3 to B1, etc. Basically any possible combination from the tree. Obviously I can only copy properties present in the source type, that **must also** be present in the target type.

Iterating the properties of the source type is easy as

```
var sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties();
```

However how do I check which property is declared on the target type? Simply checking by name is not enough, as they might have different types. Also in the past I made bad experiences with duplicate properties using `new`.

Unfortunately C# or .NET has no built-in method to check if a type has a certain `PropertyInfo` like `Type.HasProperty(PropertyInfo)`. The best I could come up with is to check if the property was declared by a shared base type.

```
public static void CopyProperties(object source, object target)
{
    var targetType = target.GetType();
    var sharedProperties =source.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(targetType));

    foreach (var property in sharedProperties)
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(source);
        if (property.CanWrite)
            property.SetValue(target, value);
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is there a better solution?

Comment: Did you try to use AutoMapper? You can possibly configure it to copy all same-name properties of one type to another without implementing it yourself.

Comment: I am aware of AutoMapper, but it seemed overkill to add the dependency just for this use-case. It's not a single application, but part of a framework, so adding dependencies requires more caution.

Comment: @Toxantron it's probably not overkill, if you have to do this dynamically,  If you know the models and its only for a few or base types you can create a manual adapter, but if it frequent or dynamic just use automapper, writing a tool with reflection will be slow compared to automapper.

Comment: Just dropping in the +1 on automapper. Its very lightweight and widely used and loved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't require inheritance.  It copies properties from one object (of one type) to another (of another type) as long as the names and types match.

You create an instance of once of these property copier objects for each pair of types you want to be able to copy from/to.  The copier object is immutable once created, so it can be long-lived, static, used from many threads (after created), etc.

Here's the code for the PropertyCopier class.  You need to specify the source and destination types when you create an object of this type.

```
public class PropertyCopier<TSource, TDest> where TSource : class where TDest : class
{
    private List<PropertyCopyPair> _propertiesToCopy = new List<PropertyCopyPair>();

    public PropertyCopier()
    {
        //get all the readable properties of the source type
        var sourceProps = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<Type, MethodInfo>>();
        foreach (var prop in typeof(TSource).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            if (prop.CanRead)
            {
                sourceProps.Add(prop.Name, new Tuple<Type, MethodInfo>(prop.PropertyType, prop.GetGetMethod()));
            }
        }

        //now walk though the writeable properties of the destination type
        //if there's a match by name and type, keep track of them.

        foreach (var prop in typeof(TDest).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            if (prop.CanWrite)
            {
                if (sourceProps.ContainsKey(prop.Name) && sourceProps[prop.Name].Item1 == prop.PropertyType)
                {
                    _propertiesToCopy.Add (new PropertyCopyPair(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType, sourceProps[prop.Name].Item2, prop.GetSetMethod()));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Copy(TSource source, TDest dest)
    {
        foreach (var prop in _propertiesToCopy)
        {
            var val = prop.SourceReader.Invoke(source, null);
            prop.DestWriter.Invoke(dest, new []{val});
        }
    }
}
```

It relies on a helper class that looks like (this can get stripped down; the extra properties where to help with debugging (and might be useful to you)).

```
public class PropertyCopyPair
{
    public PropertyCopyPair(string name, Type theType, MethodInfo sourceReader, MethodInfo destWriter)
    {
        PropertyName = name;
        TheType = theType;
        SourceReader = sourceReader;
        DestWriter = destWriter;
    }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public Type TheType { get; set; }
    public MethodInfo SourceReader { get; set; }
    public MethodInfo DestWriter { get; set; }
}
```

I also created another real simple class for testing:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public Type TheType { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }
}
```

With all that in place, this code exercises the copier class:

```
 var copier = new PropertyCopier<PropertyCopyPair, TestClass>();
 var source = new PropertyCopyPair("bob", typeof(string), null, null);
 var dest = new TestClass {Other = "other", PropertyName = "PropertyName", TheType = this.GetType()};
 copier.Copy(source, dest);
```

When you run it, all the properties of the source that have a property in the destination that have the same name and type will get copied.

If you want to restrict the source and destination types to a common base class, you can do this:

```
public class PropertyCopierCommonBase<TSource, TDest, TBase> : PropertyCopier<TSource, TBase>
    where TBase : class where TSource : class, TBase where TDest : class, TBase
{  }
```

If you don't want two classes, just declare the original `PropertyCopier` class with the three type parameters above, and that set of generic constraints.

Comment: Edited my post to add the optional restriction that the two types (source and destination) must have a common base class (i.e., added the `PropertyCopierCommonBase` class

Comment: This won't work for Nested Classes which require have the same properties but different types, and this uses reflection so it will be Slow, the OP should be using automapper.

Comment: How do you think Automapper works?  If you look at the code, there's a lot of reflection in the constructor.  That's reasonably slow.  However, once a copier object is constructed, it can last forever (it's immutable and rather small).  Once you have one, the copying is done by Invoking two MethodInfo instances per property (one for the get, one for the set).  Invoking a MethodInfo is only marginally slower than invoking a Delegate (which is marginally slower than the callvirt that invokes a regular function).  The idea is to put all the work in the constructor, and make the operation fast.

Comment: Automapper uses castle proxies, it avoids invoking through reflection, it builds its maps once.   e.g it avoids this: `var val = prop.SourceReader.Invoke(source, null);` It also support reusing it's maps. I don't really have an issue with this solution, it more that I don't see that it makes sense to recreate the wheel for a small dependency